# How do I remove the grid overlay when viewing photos on my Nikon D5600?

Tags: camera-controls, features, nikon-d5600

I have a Nikon D5600. I must have changed a setting and don't know how to make the grid overlay go away when viewing photos; i.e., a black screen with "longitude and latitude lines," which I don't want, overlaying the photo.

I am new to this camera and trying to learn how to get correct settings for normal telephoto pics. I want to use manual mode, not automatic mode.

What would cause  this screen to appear after taking a photo? (*This just happened today when trying to changing settings, some of which I don't understand.*)

How do I change this setting back to view normal photos?

Comment: Do you mean a grid pattern overlay ? Do you have the user manual ?  Have you scrolled through the menu settings to find user preferences regarding viewfinder ? First thing you should do is learn to understand your camera by reading the manual and doing online research. And practicing what you have read.

Comment: What is "*normal telephoto pics*" ?  Do you understand what  manual mode is and how to adjust the settings on your camera based on the information given to you by taking a meter reading ?  There is no universal  "*correct settings for normal telephoto pics*" Settings needed will be  based on the amount of light in the scene, the distance to the subject, the lens and the characteristics that you want in the photo ( depth of field, highlights, shadows, to name a few ) Questions are easier to answer if you  explain in detail what you have done and any/all info you can think to add.

Comment: Take a photo of it with your phone & add to your question. The view options on Nikon are accessed by clicking the 4-way+OK button to the right of the screen up or down, but I don't recognise from your description which view that might be.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the word "grid" in the section of your camera's [reference manual](https://www.lensrentals.com/product-assets/ccc18a91-2f71-4233-b3fa-eacf0b1a0628/D5600%20reference%20manual.pdf) that covers how to view/review images on your camera after shooting them. Almost all digital interchangeable lens cameras have an option to turn on or off a grid pattern when viewing images on the camera's LCD screen.

If the issue you are describing is occuring when you're looking through the viewfinder to compose a photo, then look for "viewfinder grid display".

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

First check if switching through the view modes when pressing up and down while reviewing a picture already cycles through one mode that shows the picture without additional elements.

Additionally, you can set the grid in MENU - Custom Settings (the one with the small pencil) - Viewfinder Grid Settings. You can also set the info you see in the viewfinder and the live view with the info button.

Answer (score 1):

The grid should only show up if you go into the retouch menu and select straighten. I'm not finding any other selection to cause that.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why people thought it was necessary to edit the original question to ask something it doesn't ask. There was no mention of a grid overlay in the original question because no grid was being asked about. The "latitude and longitude lines" in the original question don't imply a grid, they imply the location information box (which displays the latitude and longitude)>

The solution is to use the directional controller in playback mode, as detailed in other answers.